# Window opens another window preventing me from WinActivating the original window

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I have a window that opens another window which has the same specifications as the original window on Window Spy except for the title. But the title for the new window changes every time it is opened (The title for the original window can change as well.). I currently use WinActivate to activate the original window but it brings up the new window. I currently use move my mouse and left click to activate the original window (if the new window is not maximized) and I'm able to proceed to the next step in the macro of clicking a button in the original window and finish my macro. But if the new window is full screen, then I'm not able to "move my mouse to click" on the original window and continue with the rest of the macro. It will hold up the macro until I manually click on the original screen and complete the next step in the macro.

Comment: I don't know if there's a more elegant way, but you could have it send alt-tab to switch to the previous window.

Comment: The macro might be used after the new window opens and then using another program/window so alt-tab might not always bring up the window I want.

Comment: My thought would be that as long as the original window's title won't be changing between when you start the macro and when it ends, you could perhaps save the title of the original window to a variable and use that to activate the original window whenever it gets defocused.